Entity Framework Core problem: error within getting record: Unable to cast object of type
I have a problem that when I call multiple repository types in one class in one scope, I get an error:

System.InvalidCastException HResult=0x80004002 Message=Unable to cast object of type 'PortfolioManager.Base.Entities.RecordEntity' to type 'PortfolioManager.Base.Entities.CommodityEntity'. Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational StackTrace: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.d__20.MoveNext()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.d__67`1.MoveNext()

I haven't found a solution. Repositories inherit from a base repository and implement an interface. Project: https://github.com/TomasSobotaT/Portfolio_Manager_V2
public class BaseRepository<T>(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext, IUserContext userContext) : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity 
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
    protected readonly IUserContext userContext = userContext;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> dbSet = applicationDbContext.Set<T>();

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await dbSet.Where(r => !r.IsDeleted).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        return await dbSet.Where(r => r.Id == id  
                                      && !r.IsDeleted)
                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
    {
        entity.UpdatedBy = userContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
        entity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

        dbSet.Update(entity);

        await SaveChangesToDatabaseAsync();
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        entity.UpdatedBy = userContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
        entity.CreatedBy = userContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;

        entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        entity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

        await dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        await SaveChangesToDatabaseAsync();
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        var entity = await GetAsync(id);

        if (entity is not null)
        {
            entity.UpdatedBy = userContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
            entity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            entity.IsDeleted = true;
            await UpdateAsync(entity);
        }

        await SaveChangesToDatabaseAsync();
    }

    private async Task SaveChangesToDatabaseAsync()
    {
        await this.applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public class CommodityRepository(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext, IUserContext userContext)
    : BaseRepository<CommodityEntity>(applicationDbContext, userContext), ICommodityRepository
{
}

public interface ICommodityRepository : IBaseRepository<CommodityEntity>
{
}


 modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>().UseTpcMappingStrategy();

 modelBuilder.Entity<RecordEntity>(entity =>
 {
     entity.HasBaseType<BaseEntity>();

     entity.HasOne(r => r.User)
         .WithMany(u => u.Records)
         .HasForeignKey(r => r.UserId)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

     entity.HasOne(r => r.Commodity)
         .WithMany(c => c.Records)
         .HasForeignKey(r => r.CommodityId)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

     entity.Property(p => p.Amount).HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");
 });

 modelBuilder.Entity<CommodityEntity>(entity =>
 {
     entity.HasBaseType<BaseEntity>();

     entity.HasOne(c => c.Price)
         .WithMany(p => p.Commodity)
         .HasForeignKey(c => c.PriceId)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
 });

 modelBuilder.Entity<PriceEntity>(entity =>
 {
     entity.HasBaseType<BaseEntity>();

     entity.Property(p => p.PriceCzk).HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");
     entity.Property(p => p.PriceUsd).HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");
 });

public class RecordEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public UserEntity User { get; set; }

    public int UserId {  get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public int CommodityId { get; set; }

    public CommodityEntity Commodity { get; set; }
}

public class UserEntity : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public ICollection<RecordEntity> Records { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class CommodityEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CommodityTypes CommodityType {  get; set; }

    public ICollection<RecordEntity> Records { get; set; }

    public int PriceId { get; set; }

    public PriceEntity Price { get; set; }
}


This is not the complete error message. The message looks like this: Unable to cast object of type '<source type>' to type '<destination type>'. Please post the full message. Also we would like to know on which code line the error occurs.

How are you setting T in DbSet to access various objects?

The clear error is e.g. "Error within getting record: Unable to cast object of type 'PortfolioManager.Base.Entities.RecordEntity' to type 'PortfolioManager.Base.Entities.CommodityEntity'. If I call only one repository instance in the service, it returns the data fine. The problem is if I call then another repo type. In this case first recordRepository and then commodityRepository.

each repository inherits from BaseRepository and from an interface (e.g. ICommodityRepository), which in turn inherits from IBaseRepository

You should show the running code that actually throws the exception. We're only seeing some repository class. Side note: a repository should not save changes to a database. It greatly hampers saving more complex operations in one transaction. Also, you probably don't need AddAsync + the obligatory side note: DbSet<T> already implements the repository pattern.

System.InvalidCastException
HResult=0x80004002
Message=Unable to cast object of type 'PortfolioManager.Base.Entities.RecordEntity' to type 'PortfolioManager.Base.Entities.CommodityEntity'.
Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__20.MoveNext()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.d__67`1.MoveNext()

I made a test method directly in the controller and it throws the same error when I call the second tail.
  ' [HttpGet("Test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        var x = await priceRepository.GetAsync(1);
        var y = await commodityRepository.GetAsync(1);
        var z = await recordRepository.GetAsync(1);

        return Ok(z);
    }'


I have registered my dbContext as a transient and and it works, but iis it a right solution?                                                              builder.Services.AddTransient(provider =>
{
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
});

Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

You are trying to assign a RecordEntity to a CommodityEntity somewhere. So far we see only EF code lines in the error message. Further down in the call stack you will see your methods including the line numbers (if compiled in Debug mode).

I've added the whole error

There seems to be a mapping problem. Is there an inheritance relationship between RecordEntity and CommodityEntity? Are they mapped to the same table or is one of them an owned type of the other or something?

I've added the configuration to the question. They all inherit from a common entity.

Are the Records properties in User and Commodity of a RecordEntity collection type?

Yes...I have added entities to main question.... as I wrote, dbcontext as transient works, but as scope there is this error. But common practice is context as scope... tahts is why I originally thought it was a bug in the repository

There is not enough info provided to fully resolve the issue. Hovever you can use some thing like this   in the RecordEntity class.
public static implicit operator RecordEntity(ComodityEntity comodityEntity)
    {
        return new RecordEntity
        {
            // For example
            Id = comodityEntity.Id,
            Name = comodityEntity.Name,
            ParentId = comodityEntity.ParentId
        };
    }

If this is not the solution to your issue you should use the debugger on the controller or the service where you use the RecordEntity repository.

I don't know, I have a pretty standard repository and entities, I wouldn't expect to have to bend it like that. Especially since transient DBContext works fine, but scoped doesn't... But common practice is scoped. I have provide a full solution on github...
